# How to double protect admin access in PyroCMS

Tags: php, htaccess, security, htpasswd

I have read how to protect admin folder with *.htaccess* and *.htpasswd* file but in PyroCMS admin login (ex: `example.com/admin`) just only routing system (no admin folder yet).

So, how can I double protect my admin access?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around what you're trying to accomplish. Can you elaborate on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your not seeing admin directory is because the URL's are generated using the SQL/CMS and physical paths do not actually exist. You can however make a folder called admin and then stick the htaccess file into to there and it should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the access to the admin with the htaccess to your IP, however, if you have a dynamic IP you might lock yourself out.

To do this place a .htaccess in your admin folder and put the following lines in

```
order deny,allow
allow from 222.222.222.222 (replace with your IP address)
deny from all
```